# php preg-replace fatal situation

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i need to transform nubmer to string (dividing each 3 numbers by space, i.e **20000 => 20 000**, **1400000 => 1 400 000**)

my code:

`$cena = '20000';`

`$cena = preg_replace('/\D+/g', '', $cena);`

`$cena = preg_replace('/\d(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g', '$& ', $cena);`

this results in:

`Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'g' in myfile.php on line xxx`

what's wrong?

Comment: don't use preg_replace, use number_format()

Comment: @Dagon one moment gonna to try

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$number=1400000;
$format = number_format($number, 0, '', ' ');

echo $format; //1 400 000
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're trying to do a global replace using the `g` modifier. **[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)** doesn't support a `g` modifier, hence the error you're getting.

Instead, preg_replace takes an optional `limit` parameter which determines the maximum number of replacements that will be done. It defaults to -1, which means unlimited. In other words, it's already doing what you're trying to do.

From the manual page:

```
mixed preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement ,
                     mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] )
```